# How to compile java code with swift in XCode

Tags: ios, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I use J2Objc by Xcode build rules in Xcode(swift).

1. Write a java file(People.java)
   2.make settings for build rules, and add the custom script as the following:

   "${J2OBJC_HOME}/j2objc" -d  ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR} -sourcepath     "${PROJECT_DIR}/iOSApp-Swift" --no-package-directories  **-use-arc** ${INPUT_FILE_PATH};

Note: i enable the ARC

3. add the bridging-header file and import People.h file.
4. call some function from People class in viewcontroller file.

When I build the project ,failed:'People.h not found'.

And When i build before importing and using the People.h, then implement to import People.h file and  calling some function from People class in viewcontroller file, and build the project. It works.

I think the problem caused by J2objc not convert java file to .h/.m file before build the bridging-header file. Who knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add People.java to your Xcode target's "Compile Sources" build phase. When that phase run, it will compile each file using either built-in rules for Objective C files, or your custom build rule for Java files.

Comment: The file has been in 'Compile Sources'.

Comment: If you add a .java file to Compile Sources, then there needs to be a Build Rule that invokes j2objc (otherwise Xcode doesn't know how to build that file, and ignores it). Otherwise, add the People.m file generated by j2objc to Compile Sources.